# .net Core Mailkit send attachement from array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email-attachments, memorystream, mailkit

I am testing .Net Core MVC, which does not support System.Net.Mail, the only alternative I found is Mailkit, works well but can't figure out how to send attachments that I have stored in my database as binary.  I used the following in MVC 5:

```
     var mail = new MailMessage();
     mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(attachment), 
     attachmentName, attachmentType));
```

How can I do it in MailKit.

Comment: So, what is the problem? is it working or you have an issue?

Comment: It worked with MVC 5 and System.Net.Mail. I want to use Mailkit.

Comment: Show your current code that uses Mailkit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a builder and then add the attachments to it, the attachments can be either IFromFile or in Binary string. 
Hope this helps.

```
public async void SendEmail(string mailTo, string mailFrom, string cc, string subject, string message)
{
    var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
    if (cc != null)
    {
        emailMessage.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(cc)); 
    }

    emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("SenderName", "UserName"));
    emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("mailTo"));
    emailMessage.Subject = subject;
    var builder = new BodyBuilder { TextBody = message };

    //Fetch the attachments from db
    //considering one or more attachments
    if (attachments != null)
    {
        foreach (var attachment in attachments.ToList())
        {
            builder.Attachments.Add(attachmentName, attachment, ContentType.Parse(attachmentType));
        }
    }
    emailMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential
        {
            UserName = "USERNAME",
            Password = "PASSWORD"
        };
        await client.AuthenticateAsync(credentials);
        await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);              
    }   }
```

Comment: The Attachment constructor takes only one argument. Based on jstedfast answer https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/445.  I used 
  builder.Attachments.Add(attachmentName, attachment, ContentType.Parse(attachmentType));